# Absolute value in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

It is one step in exercise 3.6.4 in Grimmett and stirzaker that I don't understand: Let $X$ and $Y$ be discrete random variables with mean $0$, variance $1$, and covariance $\rho$. Show that $\mathbb{E}(\max\{ X^2, Y^2\}) \leq 1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}.$

The solution writes: $\max(u,v)=\frac{1}{2}(u,v)+\frac{1}{2}|u-v|$, and therefore
$$
\mathbb{E}(\max\{ X^2, Y^2\})=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}(X^2+Y^2)+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}|(X-Y)(X+Y)|\\
\leq 1+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\mathbb{E}((X-Y)^2)\mathbb{E}((X+Y)^2)}=\cdots
$$

Now $\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}(X^2+Y^2)=1$, so we need $\mathbb{E}|(X-Y)(X+Y)| \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}((X-Y)^2)\mathbb{E}((X+Y)^2)}$. What confuses me is that the absolute sign on the LHS is not in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and I think $\mathbb{E}(X-Y)(X+Y) < \mathbb{E}|(X-Y)(X+Y)|$, so how can we get the $\leq$?

Do I learn about stuff like the Cauchy-Schwarz inquality and Fubini's theorem in real analysis?

Comment: If $X$ is a random variable so is $|X|$. Why can't you just apply C-S with absolute values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory) [with finite second moments] is
$$E[UV] \le \sqrt{E[U^2]E[V^2]},$$
which attains equality when $V$ is [almost surely] a scalar multiple of $U$.

With $U=|X-Y|$ and $V=|X+Y|$ we obtain the inequality in your question.